# Keep getting Exceptions

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

I am trying to read two files, match them, then print another file as result. But i keep getting this `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. I have no idea how to fix it, can someone help me please? Here is my code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

class Test{
    final static char[][] DIG_CHAR = {{}, {}, {'A', 'B', 'C'}, {'D', 'E', 'F'}, {'G', 'H', 'I'}, {'J', 'K', 'L'}, {'M', 'N', 'O'}, {'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S'}, {'T', 'U', 'V'}, {'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'}};

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        String s1 = "telephone.txt";
        String s2 = "sample.txt";

        Process(s1, s2);
    }

    public static void Process(String s1, String s2) throws IOException {

        int size43 = ThreeCharacters(s2);
        int size44 = FourCharacters(s2);
        int size47 = SevenCharacters(s2);

        String[] WordsOf3 = Store3Words(s2, size43);
        String[] WordsOf4 = Store4Words(s2, size44);
        String[] WordsOf7 = Store7Words(s2, size47);

        String[] s = Char2Dig(WordsOf3);
        String[] p = Char2Dig(WordsOf4);
        String[] q = Char2Dig(WordsOf7);

        Print3(WordsOf3, s, s1);
        Print4(WordsOf4, p, s1);
        Print7(WordsOf7, q, s1);

    }


    public static int ThreeCharacters(String s2) throws IOException {

        Scanner in = new Scanner(new File(s2));
        int count = 0;

        while (in.hasNextLine()) {
            in.nextLine();
            if (in.nextLine().length() == 3) {
                count++;
            }
        }

        in.close();
        return count;
    }

    public static int FourCharacters(String s2) throws IOException {

        Scanner in = new Scanner(new File(s2));
        int count = 0;

        while (in.hasNextLine()) {
            in.nextLine();
            if (in.nextLine().length() == 4) {
                count++;
            }
        }

        in.close();
        return count;
    }

    public static int SevenCharacters(String s2) throws IOException {

        Scanner in = new Scanner(new File(s2));
        int count = 0;

        while (in.hasNextLine()) {
            in.nextLine();
            if(in.nextLine().length() == 7) {
                count++;
            }
        }

        in.close();
        return count;
    }

    public static String[] Store3Words(String s2, int size) throws IOException {
        //Here is where i keep getting the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException, probably same as the next two methods

        String[] words = new String[size];
        String temp = "";
        Scanner in = new Scanner(new File(s2));
        int i = 0;

        while (in.hasNextLine()) {
            temp = in.nextLine();
            if (temp.length() == 3) {
                words[i] = temp;
                i++;
            }

        }

        in.close();
        return words;
    }

    public static String[] Store4Words(String s2, int size) throws IOException {

        String[] words = new String[size];
        String temp = "";
        Scanner in = new Scanner(new File(s2));
        int i = 0;

        while (in.hasNextLine()) {
            temp = in.nextLine();
            if (temp.length() == 4) {
                words[i] = temp;
                i++;
            }
        }

        in.close();
        return words;
    }

    public static String[] Store7Words(String s2, int size) throws IOException {

        String[] words = new String[size];
        String temp = "";
        Scanner in = new Scanner(new File(s2));
        int i = 0;

        while (in.hasNextLine()) {
            temp = in.nextLine();
            if (temp.length() == 7) {
                words[i] = temp;
                i++;
            }
        }

        in.close();
        return words;
    }

    public static String[] Char2Dig(String[] arr)  {        // ||

        String temp = "";
        String q = "";
        String str = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            temp = arr[i];
            str = "";
            for (int j = 0; j < temp.length(); j++) {
                for (int m = 2; m < DIG_CHAR.length; m++) {
                    for (int k = 0; k < DIG_CHAR[m].length; k++) {
                        if (temp.charAt(j) == DIG_CHAR[m][k]) {
                            q = q + DIG_CHAR[m];
                            str = str + q;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if (q == "") {
                        continue;
                    }

                    break;
                }
                q = "";
            }

            arr[i] = str;
        }
        return arr;
    }

    public static void Print3(String[] WordsOf3, String[] arr, String s1) throws IOException {

        PrintWriter outfile = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("result.txt"));
        Scanner in = new Scanner(new File(s1));
        String temp = "";

        while (in.hasNextLine()) {
            temp = in.nextLine().substring(4, 7);
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                if (arr[i] == temp) {
                    outfile.println(temp + ": " + WordsOf3[i]);
                }
            }
        }


        outfile.close();
    }

    public static void Print4(String[] WordsOf4, String[] arr, String s1) throws IOException {

        PrintWriter outfile = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("result.txt"));
        Scanner in = new Scanner(new File(s1));
        String temp = "";

        while (in.hasNextLine()) {
            temp = in.nextLine().substring(7, 11);
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                if (arr[i] == temp) {
                    outfile.println(temp + ": " + WordsOf4[i]);
                }
            }
        }

        outfile.close();
    }

    public static void Print7(String[] WordsOf7, String[] arr, String s1) throws IOException {

        PrintWriter outfile = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("result.txt"));
        Scanner in = new Scanner(new File(s1));
        String temp = "";

        while (in.hasNextLine()) {
            temp = in.nextLine().substring(4);
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                if (arr[i] == temp) {
                    outfile.println(temp + ": " + WordsOf7[i]);
                }
            }
        }

        outfile.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: Post the full code to attract more attention to your question

Comment: I have no idea why are you guys teasing me. Like i said, I'm new to programming. You rather waste 30 secs of fixing my grammar/teasing me , instead of helping.

Comment: I did not mean to tease you my friend. I am far from being the best program writer otherwise I would have solve the problem right the way. It happens that I stop here few time after you post your question, and I wanted your question to read by the most, that is why I suggested. And I will suggest one more thing if you don't mind. Can you add some tags? like java if this is a java code as I can say. The tags will definitely opens your question to the appropriate people to answer it.

Comment: It's good to read up on debuggers and how to use them in the IDE you are using. This will allow you to place breakpoints and debug values of variables and classes that you are encountering problems with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you do not count right. You miss the number line of 3, 4 or 7 characters. Let's look at your code, method `ThreeCharacters`:

```
public static int ThreeCharacters(String s2) throws IOException {

    Scanner in = new Scanner(new File(s2));
    int count = 0;

    while (in.hasNextLine()) {
        in.nextLine();
        if (in.nextLine().length() == 3) {
            count++;
        }
    }

    in.close();
    return count;
}
```

`in.nextLine()` reads and skips one line, then `if (in.nextLine().length() == 3)` again reads and skips another line. At the end, you check only one line over two. The suggestion is to remove the `in.nextLine()` that is not doing anything, I guess. And if for any reason you put it on purpose, add the same line in `Store3Words` so that you also process only one line over two. This will solve the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, but you will possibly have other problem in your code, because as beginner, you did not follow the path you are supposed to follow in programming: write one method, test and make sure it is working and move to the next method.

Altogether, I suggest you write a single method to count and a single one to store, your code can become as compact as this:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

class TestApp{
    final static char[][] DIG_CHAR = {{}, {}, {'A', 'B', 'C'}, {'D', 'E', 'F'},
    {'G', 'H', 'I'}, {'J', 'K', 'L'}, {'M', 'N', 'O'}, {'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S'},
    {'T', 'U', 'V'}, {'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'}};

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        String s1 = "telephone.txt";
        String s2 = "sample.txt";

        Process(s1, s2);
    }

    public static void Process(String s1, String s2) throws IOException {

        int size43 = count(s2, 3);
        int size44 = count(s2, 4);
        int size47 = count(s2, 7);
        /////
        System.out.println("lines of 3: "+size43 );
        System.out.println("lines of 4: "+size44 );
        System.out.println("lines of 7: "+size47 );
        /////

        String[] WordsOf3 = store(s2, size43, 3);
        String[] WordsOf4 = store(s2, size44, 4);
        String[] WordsOf7 = store(s2, size47, 7);
        /////
        System.out.println("lines of 3" );
        for(int i = 0; i<size43; i++){
            System.out.println( WordsOf3[i] );
        }
        System.out.println("lines of 4" );
        for(int i = 0; i<size44; i++){
            System.out.println( WordsOf4[i] );
        }
        System.out.println("lines of 7" );
        for(int i = 0; i<size47; i++){
            System.out.println( WordsOf7[i] );
        }
        /////

        String[] s = Char2Dig(WordsOf3);
        String[] p = Char2Dig(WordsOf4);
        String[] q = Char2Dig(WordsOf7);

        Print3(WordsOf3, s, s1);
        Print4(WordsOf4, p, s1);
        Print7(WordsOf7, q, s1);

    }

    /** Single method that returns the number of lines of given number of char
    *   With this single method, no need to write ThreeCharacters, FourCharacters
    *   and SevenCharacters
    */
    public static int count(String fName, int nChar) throws IOException {

        Scanner in = new Scanner(new File(fName));
        int count = 0;
        String tmp; // Note the tmp variable, so that we do not advance twice

        while (in.hasNextLine()) {
            if (in.nextLine().length() == nChar) {
                count++;
            }
        }

        in.close();
        return count;
    }

    /** Single method that returns all the lines of given number of char
    *   With this single method, no need to write Store3Words, Store4Words
    *   and Store7Words
    */
    public static String[] store(String fName, int size, int nChar) throws IOException {

        String[] words = new String[size];
        String temp = "";
        Scanner in = new Scanner(new File(fName));
        int i = 0;

        while (in.hasNextLine()) {
            temp = in.nextLine();
            if (temp.length() == nChar) {
                words[i] = temp;
                i++;
            }
        }

        in.close();
        return words;
    }

    public static String[] Char2Dig(String[] arr)  {        // ||

        String temp = "";
        String q = "";
        String str = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            temp = arr[i];
            str = "";
            for (int j = 0; j < temp.length(); j++) {
                for (int m = 2; m < DIG_CHAR.length; m++) {
                    for (int k = 0; k < DIG_CHAR[m].length; k++) {
                        if (temp.charAt(j) == DIG_CHAR[m][k]) {
                            q = q + DIG_CHAR[m];
                            str = str + q;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if (q == "") {
                        continue;
                    }

                    break;
                }
                q = "";
            }

            arr[i] = str;
        }
        return arr;
    }

    public static void Print3(String[] WordsOf3, String[] arr, String s1) throws IOException {

        PrintWriter outfile = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("result.txt"));
        Scanner in = new Scanner(new File(s1));
        String temp = "";

        while (in.hasNextLine()) {
            temp = in.nextLine().substring(4, 7);
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                if (arr[i] == temp) {
                    outfile.println(temp + ": " + WordsOf3[i]);
                }
            }
        }


        outfile.close();
    }

    public static void Print4(String[] WordsOf4, String[] arr, String s1) throws IOException {

        PrintWriter outfile = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("result.txt"));
        Scanner in = new Scanner(new File(s1));
        String temp = "";

        while (in.hasNextLine()) {
            temp = in.nextLine().substring(7, 11);
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                if (arr[i] == temp) {
                    outfile.println(temp + ": " + WordsOf4[i]);
                }
            }
        }

        outfile.close();
    }

    public static void Print7(String[] WordsOf7, String[] arr, String s1) throws IOException {

        PrintWriter outfile = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("result.txt"));
        Scanner in = new Scanner(new File(s1));
        String temp = "";

        while (in.hasNextLine()) {
            temp = in.nextLine().substring(4);
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                if (arr[i] == temp) {
                    outfile.println(temp + ": " + WordsOf7[i]);
                }
            }
        }

        outfile.close();
    }

}
```

If I understood the logic behind the `Print3`, `Print4` and `Print7` I would have do the same. Also notice that I added some print statement to see what is going on. That is very helpful to see if your code is doing what it is supposed to do.